# Check if string contains substring without using indexOf - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

My function is trying to check if string contains substring without use of indexOf or regex `match` or any standard JS methods.

Please check this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/09x4Lpj2/

```js
var string1 = 'applegate';
    var string2 = 'gate';

    function containsString(string1, string2){
   var j = 0;
      var k = 0;
      var contains = 'false';
      var charArray1 = string1.split('');
      var charArray2 = string2.split('');
  
      for(var i = 0; i < charArray2.length; i++){
       j = i;
        if(charArray1[j++] != charArray2[k++]){
       contains = 'false';
        }else{
       contains = 'true';
        }   
      }
  
     console.log(contains);
    }
containsString(string1, string2);
```

This solution works only when the indexes are the same between the two strings (ex. `applegate` and `apple`). But will not work if the indexes are not the same (ex. `applegate` and `gate`). How do I manipulate the iterative values correctly so that the function returns true for both situations?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

Comment: there is not need to convert string to char array. string is already char array

Comment: Two for loops, nested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try this modified script of yours.

```js
var string1 = 'applegate';
var string2 = 'gate';
var string3 = 'apple';
var string4 = 'leg';
var string5 = 'banana';

function containsString(string1, string2){
  var charArray1 = string1.split('');
  var charArray2 = string2.split('');
  var match = 0;

  // iterate from start of 1st string until length of 1st string minus length of 2nd string
  // you don't need to iterate the last part that is not longer than 2nd string since it will be false
  for(var i = 0; i < charArray1.length - charArray2.length + 1; i++){
    // reset match counter on every iteration
    match = 0;
    // iterate the 2nd string
    for(var j = 0; j < charArray2.length; j++){
      // compare corresponding char location
      if(charArray1[i+j] == charArray2[j]){
        match++;
        // just to check in console
        console.log(i, j, match, charArray1[i+j], charArray2[j]);
      } else {
        // just to check in console
        console.log(i, j, match, charArray1[i+j], charArray2[j]);
        // if not match, just skip current check
        break;
      }
      // if match already found, stop the checks, and return true
      if(match == charArray2.length){
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  // match not found until end of iteration
  return false;
}

console.log(containsString(string1, string2));
console.log(containsString(string1, string3));
console.log(containsString(string1, string4));   
console.log(containsString(string1, string5));   // haystack does not contain needle
console.log(containsString(string4, string1));   // haystack is shorter than needle
```

Comment: Thanks you. This is really helpfull. Especially for environments that doesn't support indexOf method like IE < 9 etc...

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.
Regex can be used.. Unless even that is also prohibited..

```
 function containsString(string1, string2){
    console.log(string1.match(string2) != null ? "Yes" : "No");
 }
```

[Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: thank you for the alternative solution :) however, i am trying my best to avoid regex `match` or any other methods so that I can develop an algorithm for this type of situation.

Comment: This will not work if `string2` contains regex metacharacters like `.*[]()`

Comment: Ya agreed. But apparently Regex is out of question..So this cannot be THE Answer.. just a starting point. : )

Answer (score 0):

This code has a logical problem，Only to determine whether the last character of A is equal to the corresponding character of B，Maybe the following code is what you want,add a line of code.

```
var string1 = 'applegate';
var string2 = 'gate';

function containsString(string1, string2){
  var j = 0;
  var k = 0;
  var contains = 'false';
  var charArray1 = string1.split('');
  var charArray2 = string2.split('');

  for(var i = 0; i < charArray2.length; i++){
    j = i;
    if(charArray1[j++] != charArray2[k++]){
      contains = 'false';
      break;
    }else{
      contains = 'true';
    }   
  }

 console.log(contains);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this without using any inbuilt functions

```
function subSearch(long,short){
var count = 0
for(i = 0;i < long.length; i++){
  for(j = 0;j < short.length; j++){
    if(short[j] != long[i + j]){
      break;
    }
    if((j+1) == short.length){
      count++;
    }
  }
}
return count;
}
```